# Can't access my generated list of input

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I dunno if i'm unlucky or what, but this is the second time i do something that's supposed to work, and it seems like the problem come from another galaxy :

I'm working on a MVC/Jquery web app , here's my "form" :
(note that @item.MV return "CH" 5 times  and @item.Cnts return values from 10 to 20)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Time)
{
    <input id="@item.MV" type="text" value="@item.Cnts" />
}
```

and my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#CH:eq(2)").css("color","green");
});
```

If i understand well, Jquery is supposed to launch this piece of code when the document is **ready** (which mean everything is "supposed" to be loaded), but it just won't work, and when i try to do an alert of the value, it says "undefined", but the input contains something.

Anyone has a clue ?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Comment: why you are using ID? use Class.

Comment: What does the resulting markup look like?  The JavaScript code isn't seeing your server-side Razor syntax, it's seeing the resulting HTML.  Show that.

Answer (score 2):

use `class` attribute instead of `ID` :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Time)
{
    <input class="@item.MV" type="text" value="@item.Cnts" />
}
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(".CH:eq(2)").css("color","green");
});
```

**[JSFilddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4fj8q/)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use an id more than once, use the class property. However, you don't need jquery for your example. Psuedo code since I'm not very familiar with razor:

```
@int count = 0;
@foreach (var item in Model.Time)
{
    @string style = count != 2 ? string.Empty : "style=\"background: green;\"";
    <input id="@item.MV" type="text" value="@item.Cnts" @style />
    @count++;
}
```